# JavaScript передача object HtmlVideoElement

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Получаю доступ к камере пользователя следующим кодом:

```
var video = document.querySelector("#my-video");
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } };
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remoteVideo");
var localMediaStream;
  function getMyCam(){
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function(mediaStream) {
        localMediaStream = mediaStream;
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        video.srcObject = mediaStream;
        console.log(mediaStream);
        video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
          video.play();
        };
      })
      .catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); }); // always check for errors at the end.


      cameraInterval = setInterval(function(){ snapshot();}, 3000);
    }
```

Видео дублируется в canvas с интервалом cameraInterval:

```
function snapshot(){
             if(localMediaStream){
              console.log(video);
                    ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
              }
      }
```

У пользователя есть активное соединение с сервером. c определённом интервалом посылается изображение на сервер:

```
function sendVideo(){
    conn.send('{"type":"video","video": "'+ video + '"}');
  }
```

На стороне сервера это сообщение обрабатывается и отсылается нужным людям), на стороне этих людей:

```
case 'video':
          console.log(response.video);
          ctx.drawImage(response.video, 0, 0);
          break;
```

При вызове ctx.drawImage вылазит ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
    at WebSocket.conn.onmessage
```

Понимаю что приходит не тот объект, хотя посылаю object HTMLVideoElement. Возникает вопрос, как правильно послать объект видео что-бы его отрисовать в canvas других людей?

Comment: а что консоль показывает?

Comment: Консоль выводит ту ошибку, что описал. Хотя когда вывожу `console.log(response.video)` консоль пишет `[object HTMLVideoElement]`

Comment: придется послать картинку в виде массива байтов..

Comment: а разве консоль не должна показать `object HTMLVideoElement` в поном виде? Может ответ сервера нужно распарсить сначала?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ
Вот и я о том же думал. В JavaScript не сильно силён, вот и спросил помощи здесь)

Comment: @Дмытрык на стороне клиента `console.log(video)` выводит полностью `<video id="my-video"></div>`. Ответ от сервера я распарсил `var response = JSON.parse(event.data)`/

Comment: Почему тогда консоль показывает `[object HTMLVideoElement]`?  Может там двойная сериализация? Либо неправильная сериализация самого объекта

Comment: @Дмытрык к json привожу так: `data = JSON.stringify({
     "type": "video",
     "video": document.querySelector("#my-video")
   });` и отправляю. В таком случае когда вывожу `console.log(response.video)` выводится `[]    lenght:0     __proto__ : Array(0)`

Comment: `document.querySelector("#my-video")` - возвращает `DOM-element`. С помощью  `JSON.stringify` он не сериализуется. Попробуйте посмотреть здесь https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer. Если не поможет, то скорее всего, нужно брать данные, а не `DOM-element`

Comment: @Дмытрык сериализовал с помощью вашего способа, вот что вышло `<video xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="my-video" autoplay="true"></video>`. Возможно ли теперь это десеарилизовать?

Comment: Врядли, работайте лучше с данными, как и говорил @Stranger in the Q